# Turn UAC to Maximum Level with command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, uac

I'm writing a batch script and I have searched everywhere for a way to do this. I want to turn UAC all the way up (you know, the slider) via my batch script. I've already tried turning it on and off with this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

But I can't find a way to turn it up! Please help! There has to be a way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UAC slider is controlled by combination of several registry values. See this question: [Set UAC Level with PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/817114/set-uac-level-with-powershell). So, set desired UAC level, write down values for mentioned registry keys and apply them with `reg.exe`.

Comment: interesting... I believe I tried this and it only partially worked.

Comment: @LukeDinkler Share a details about what worked and what not and maybe we could figure this out.

Comment: Ok! I got it to work! I had a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232771.aspx for the REG_DWORD values. Thanks!